# 'People gathered around might discover' is ungrammatical. Do you agree?

Tags: grammar

I think 'People ***gathered around*** might discover' in the following sentence is ungrammatical. It should be rewritten as 'People ***gathering around*** might discover' People ***who gathered around*** might discover.' Do you agree?

> People **gathered around** might discover, in the documents coming off
>   the machine, the write­up of a colleague’s project that’s relevant to
>   their own work, or a new company policy that might affect them.

Source: Who Moved My Cube by Anne-Laure Fayard and John Weeks

Answer (score 1):

No. *People gathered round* is perfectly grammatical.

*Gathered* here is an adjective, not a passive participle. (You can see this because there is no answer to the question "who were they gathered by?")

I admit that it seems a bit anomalous that the adjective is derived from the past participle but does not have a passive meaning (unlike adjectives like "written" and "seen"). But it is not the only one: *gone*, *grown*, and *rotten* are similarly used without a passive meaning.

Comment: What's wrong with taking it as a participle here? They were gathered by agreement, or by curiosity; it's not important.

Comment: @AntonSherwood: Curiosity gathered them? An agreement gathered them? Not in my version of English.

Comment: How do you feel about “curiosity brought them”?

Comment: @AntonSherwood: that one's fine. But "curiosity gathered them" is unnaturally poetic for me.

Comment: Why don't the OP's just accept good answers? It clutters up the system so and the questions keep coming back around. Grhhh.